# How can I assign every 5th sample in my dataset as a Testing dataset and the rest of the samples as the training dataset?

Tags: r, matlab, machine-learning, dataset, classification

I have a dataset with 133 samples(133 rows and 2 coloumns(attributes)). I need to assign every 5th sample starting from 1(1st, 6th, 11th, 16th.... etc) as testing dataset and the rest as training dataset. How can I do it?

Comment: Something like `split(mydf, rownames(mydf) %in% seq(1, 133, by = 5))`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the [colon-operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) in Maltab:

```
testset = dataset(1:5:end,:)
trainingset = setdiff(dataset, testset, 'rows')
```

You can also do this without `setdiff`:

```
testset = dataset(1:5:end,:)
trainingset = dataset;
trainingset(1:5:end, :) = [];
```

Answer (score 3):

In [r](/questions/tagged/r) you can just use `seq` to generate the sequence of rows you want to keep. Then, you can either take a basic `[` based subset, or you can use `%in%` to split the dataset into two parts.

Here's an example of the latter, with some sample data:

```
set.seed(1)
mydf <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(266), ncol = 2))
mySamples <- setNames(split(mydf, rownames(mydf) %in% seq(1, 133, by = 5)),
                      c("training", "testing"))
str(mySamples)
# List of 2
#  $ training:'data.frame':  106 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ X1: num [1:106] 0.184 -0.836 1.595 0.33 0.487 ...
#   ..$ X2: num [1:106] 0.3066 -1.5364 -0.301 -0.5283 -0.0569 ...
#  $ testing :'data.frame': 27 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ X1: num [1:27] -0.6265 -0.8205 1.5118 -0.0449 0.919 ...
#   ..$ X2: num [1:27] -1.518 -0.652 -0.464 -1.286 -0.929 ...
```

---

Here's the alternative slightly more manual approach using `[`:

```
testingRows  <- seq(1, 133, by = 5)
trainingRows <- setdiff(sequence(nrow(mydf)), testingRows)
testing  <- mydf[testingRows, ]
training <- mydf[trainingRows, ]
```